# Add a column in excel sheet using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to add a column after a particular column number in excel sheet using Powershell.
I am able to add it at starting of sheet, but couldn't insert after a specific column.

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/7d471cfd-4368-46b8-962f-9583c16ad308

Comment: I had checked this link earlier. Can u tell me what does -4161 represents?

Comment: Scripting guy puts it well _"yes, minus 4161; go figure"_. This article will shine some light as the PS from my previous link is a direct adaptation:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/04/11/how-can-i-insert-a-column-into-a-spreadsheet.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
#This will insert a column at column R

$Excel = New-Object -ComObject  excel.application 
$ExcelWorkSheet = $ExcelWordBook.Worksheets.Add()
$ExcelWorkSheet.Name = "TestThis"
#do other things

$ColumnSelect = $ExcelWorkSheet.Columns("R:R")
$ColumnSelect.Insert()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alas, I agree, I have not found neither documentation or examples :-/ .
 
Nevertheless here is below how to insert a column 7th and give it a name:

```ps1
(Get-ChildItem "*.xlsb")|
    foreach-object {
        $xl=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $wb=$xl.workbooks.open($_)
        $ws = $wb.worksheets.Item(1)
        $ws.Columns.ListObject.ListColumns.Add(7)
        $ws.Cells.Item(1,7) ='Comment'
        $wb.Save()
        $xl.Quit()
        while([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject([System.__ComObject]$xl)){'released'| Out-Null}
    }
```

Best regards