# PowerShell Excel 2016 insert

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-3.0, excel-2016

Could someone tell me how to perform an insert using PowerShell for Excel 2016?

I've tried this:

```
$erow = $ws.(1,1).entirerow
$active = $eRow.activate()
$active = $eRow.insert([microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlDirection]::xlDown)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "insert"? What do you expect the code snippet to do, and what does it actually do?

Comment: [void]$ws.Range( $ws.cells(1,1), $ws.cells(1,1) ).EntireRow.Copy()
[void]$ws.cells($rowNumberToInsert,1).Insert()

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what exactly do you mean by "insert"? :)

If you would like to insert row, create an excel sheet with an "Excel table" (it's more easy to handle) & follow the recipe:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29892939/2672544

And in order to add only row in your table:

```ps1
[..]
$ws.Cells.ListObject.ListRows.Add(1)
```

And try & play with "tab tab" or better Get-Member !